# Refactor cellForRowIndexPath in UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, refactoring

I have a rather long `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. I am using parse as my backend and have a lot going on. I want to extract a lot of these conditions and put them in their own functions. Especially the PFUser query, but unfortunately I don't know whats the best way to go about it since I don't know how I can access the elements of each cell in those functions I want to write.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCells", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsFeedTableCellTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    // A drive is a post
    let drive: PFObject = self.timelineData[indexPath.row] as PFObject
    var driverId = drive.objectForKey("driver")!.objectId!
    var currentUserObjectId = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId
    if(driverId != currentUserObjectId){
        cell.requestButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.requestButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11)
        cell.requestButton.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        cell.requestButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor
        cell.requestButton.setTitle("REQUEST", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    }
    else {

        cell.requestButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.requestButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11)
        cell.requestButton.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.requestButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        cell.requestButton.setTitle("REQUEST", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.requestButton.enabled = false

    }


    // Setting up the attributes of the cell for the news feed
    cell.driveTitleTextField.text = drive.objectForKey("title") as! String
    cell.wayTextField.text = drive.objectForKey("way") as! String

    var departureDate = NSDate()
    departureDate = drive.objectForKey("departureDate") as! NSDate
    var dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateFormat = "M/dd hh:mm a"
    cell.departureDateTextField.text = dateFormat.stringFromDate(departureDate)

    if((drive.objectForKey("way")!.isEqualToString("Two Way")))
    {
        var returnDate = NSDate()
        returnDate = drive.objectForKey("returnDate") as! NSDate
        cell.returningDateTextField.text = dateFormat.stringFromDate(returnDate)
    }
    else if((drive.objectForKey("way")!.isEqualToString("One Way")))
    {
        cell.returningDateTextField.enabled = false
        cell.returningDateTextField.userInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.returningDateTextField.hidden = true
        cell.returningLabel.hidden = true
    }

    var seatNumber = NSNumber()
    seatNumber = drive.objectForKey("seatNumber") as! NSInteger
    var numberFormat = NSNumberFormatter()
    numberFormat.stringFromNumber(seatNumber)
    cell.seatNumberTextField.text = numberFormat.stringFromNumber(seatNumber)


    // this is a PFUser query so we can get the users image and name and email from the User class 
    var findDrive = PFUser.query()
    var objectId: AnyObject? = drive.objectForKey("driver")!.objectId!
    findDrive?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: objectId!)
    findDrive?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?)->Void in
        if (error == nil){
            if let actualObjects = objects {
                let possibleUser = (actualObjects as NSArray).lastObject as? PFUser
                if let user = possibleUser {
                    cell.userProfileNameLabel.text = user["fullName"] as? String
                    cell.userEmailLabel.text = user["username"] as? String

                    //Profile Image
                    cell.profileImage.alpha = 0
                    if let profileImage = user["profilePicture"] as? PFFile {
                        profileImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
                            (imageData:NSData? , error:NSError?)-> Void in

                            if(error == nil) {
                                if imageData != nil{
                                    let image:UIImage = UIImage (data: imageData!)!
                                    cell.profileImage.image = image
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                        cell.driveTitleTextField.alpha = 1
                        cell.wayTextField.alpha = 1
                        cell.profileImage.alpha = 1
                        cell.userProfileNameLabel.alpha = 1
                        cell.userEmailLabel.alpha = 1
                        cell.seatNumberTextField.alpha = 1
                        cell.returningDateTextField.alpha = 1
                        cell.departureDateTextField.alpha = 1

                    })

                }
            }

        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I came up with a way to refactor my code that I would like critiqued!

**1.** I extracted a lot of the cells configurations and put them into to functions, one for the button on the cell and the other for all the data from parse.

```
func configureDataTableViewCell(cell:NewsFeedTableCellTableViewCell, drive: PFObject)
{
    cell.driveTitleTextField.text = drive.objectForKey("title") as! String
    cell.wayTextField.text = drive.objectForKey("way") as! String
    cell.userEmailLabel.text = drive.objectForKey("username") as? String
    cell.userProfileNameLabel.text = drive.objectForKey("name") as? String

    var departureDate = NSDate()
    departureDate = drive.objectForKey("departureDate") as! NSDate
    var dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateFormat = "M/dd hh:mm a"
    cell.departureDateTextField.text = dateFormat.stringFromDate(departureDate)

    if((drive.objectForKey("way")!.isEqualToString("Two Way")))
    {
        var returnDate = NSDate()
        returnDate = drive.objectForKey("returnDate") as! NSDate
        cell.returningDateTextField.text = dateFormat.stringFromDate(returnDate)
    }
    else if((drive.objectForKey("way")!.isEqualToString("One Way")))
    {
        cell.returningDateTextField.enabled = false
        cell.returningDateTextField.userInteractionEnabled = false
        cell.returningDateTextField.hidden = true
        cell.returningLabel.hidden = true
    }

    var seatNumber = NSNumber()
    seatNumber = drive.objectForKey("seatNumber") as! NSInteger
    var numberFormat = NSNumberFormatter()
    numberFormat.stringFromNumber(seatNumber)
    cell.seatNumberTextField.text = numberFormat.stringFromNumber(seatNumber)


}

func configureButtonTableViewCell(cell:NewsFeedTableCellTableViewCell, userID: String)
{
    var currentUserObjectId = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId
    if(userID != currentUserObjectId){
        cell.requestButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.requestButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11)
        cell.requestButton.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        cell.requestButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor
        cell.requestButton.setTitle("REQUEST", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        println("orange")
    }
    else {

        cell.requestButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.requestButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11)
        cell.requestButton.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.requestButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        cell.requestButton.setTitle("REQUEST", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.requestButton.enabled = false
        println("gray")
    }

}
```

**2.** I then passed in the functions from step 1 and into my `cellForRowIndexPath`

```
    // A drive is a post
    let drive: PFObject = self.timelineData[indexPath.row] as PFObject
    var driverId : String = drive.objectForKey("driver")!.objectId!!
    configureButtonTableViewCell(cell, userID: driverId)
    configureDataTableViewCell(cell, drive: drive)
```

**3.** I stored all my PFUser data into my object when its saved instead of querying the user class. So I get the `PFUser.currentUser()` username, full name, and profile picture when they save a post.

My load data has been modified. I store all the profile pictures in there own array.

```
func loadData(){


    var findItemData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"Posts")

    findItemData.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")

    findItemData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]? , error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                self.timelineData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                self.profilePictures.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                self.timelineData = objects as! [PFObject]
                for object in objects! {

                    self.profilePictures.append(object.objectForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile)


                }

                self.newsFeedTableView.reloadData()


            }

    }
}
```

And finally, here is my updated `cellForRowIndexPath`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCells", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsFeedTableCellTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    // A drive is a post
    let drive: PFObject = self.timelineData[indexPath.row] as PFObject
    var driverId : String = drive.objectForKey("driver")!.objectId!!
    configureButtonTableViewCell(cell, userID: driverId)
    configureDataTableViewCell(cell, drive: drive)
    println(PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("username"))


    if let profileImage = drive["profilePicture"] as? PFFile {
        profileImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (imageData:NSData? , error:NSError?)-> Void in

            if(error == nil) {
                if imageData != nil{
                    let image:UIImage = UIImage (data: imageData!)!
                    cell.profileImage.image = image
                }
            }
        }

    }


    return cell
}
```

Let me know what you guys think, I want to do make my code much more readable, fast, and memory efficient.

Comment: Date formatters can be slow, if you can move them out of cellForRow, and perhaps set them on your fetched objects as a string, that might be best. Other than that, looks really good.

Comment: @BeauYoung thanks! can u give me an example of getting the date formatters out of there?

Comment: Well you have departureDate right? Why not have this in the format you need on Parse? If you can't do that, I would just create a new key on PFObject and add it there right after you have finished fetching them. Just throw them in a loop.

Comment: Did any of these answers help you?

Comment: @BeauYoung I like what you mentioned and agree that i should format them when they are fetched, but not sure where exactly, if i doit in the block of the query or right after the query? Also what do u mean "just create a new key on PFObject"? Thanks!

Comment: Right after the query is fine. I'm not entirely sure how PFObject works, but if you can use objectForKey, then I'm assuming you can use setObject:forKey:. That's where you can set your date string after you have formatted it.

Comment: so there is not setObject in parse what would be other alternatives @BeauYoung

Comment: alternative is to create your own object with the properties you need. OR set the date as a string on the parse backend, using cloud code if needed.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be doing any heavy model stuff inside cellForRow.
What you're currently trying to do will greatly slow down your UI.

In most cases you will want your model objects setup, and ready to go before you even get to cellForRow.

This means performing your Parse queries somewhere like in viewDidLoad, keep those results in an array, and when it comes time to do so, apply them to your cells in cellForRow. This way, when a user scrolls, a new query won't be dispatched for every new cell that comes into view. It will already be available.

In addition to this, should you need to make any changes to these items once they have been fetched, you can do so, and have them remain unchanged even when the user is scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor so you have some data type or group of instance variables to serve as a view model. Avoid making asynchronous calls that mutate the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Instead have your data access method mutate or recreate the view model and at the end of your callback, dispatch_async to the main queue. Give it a closure that tells your table view to reloadData and whatever else you need to do for views to show the new data.

Here's a little pseudocode to describe what I mean:

```
func loadData() {
    parseQueryWithCallback() { data in
        self.viewModel = doWhateverTransformsAreNeeded(data)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), self.tableView.reloadData)
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = dequeue(...)
    cell.thingOne = self.viewModel.things[indexPath.row].thingOne
    cell.thingTwo = self.viewModel.things[indexPath.row].thingTwo
    return cell
}
```

Comment: could you give me some code, do you need more context of the problem?

Comment: where is parseQueryWithCallback() from ?

Comment: It's pseudocode, so you replace that with whatever your real code is for getting data from Parse.

Comment: okay thanks! i want to start creating a model , for this scenario i only need one model for the posts because thats what the cell is trying to display?

Comment: Yes. It could be an Array<YourCellModelType> if that's all you need. The view model is basically whatever instance variable(s) you declare on the view controller that just hold(s) data to be used for populating the views.